# jquery focusin event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I'm validating the form input for example say First Name on click of a button.If empty i change the class to

```
    .ValidateError
{
    border: 3px solid #ff9600;
    background: #ffebe9;
    padding: 4px 4px 5px 4px;
    color: #404040;
}
```

On focus on the text box i'm trying to remove this class from the input box using the following script on `document.ready`

```
  $('#divPersonalInfo input').focusin(function () {
        $(this).removeClass().addClass('input w220');
    });
});
```

Here is the html code

```
    <div id="divPersonalInfo" class="PersonalInfo">

  <h2 id="hPersonal">
    Personal Information
  </h2>

  <div class="FormColumn FloatLeft">
    <label>
      ﬁrst name*
    </label>
    <br />
    <input maxlength="100" id="txtFirstName" placeholder="First Name" class="input w220 "/>
  </div>

  <div class="FormColumn FloatLeft">
    <label>
      last name*
    </label>
    <br />
    <input maxlength="100" id="txtLastName" placeholder="Last Name" class="input w220"/>
  </div>

  <div class="FormColumn FloatLeft">
    <label>
      email*
    </label>
    <br />
    <input maxlength="100" id="txtPersonalEmailId" placeholder="will be seen when sending your web proﬁle/app to your colleagues" class="input w220"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

But the class isn't removed on focusin

Comment: to which element the `ValidateError` class is added

Comment: actually its added on click event of an href when it tries to validate the text box for empty values

Answer (score 2):

You should write one class name if you want to remove only "ValidateError"

```
$(this).removeClass("ValidateError");
```

BTW. Using jquery you can use your focus like this

```
$(selector).focus(function)
```